# Cannot import modules from other folders

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am currently having an issue with importing files from other directories in my python project.

My current file structure is

```
Project
 - Backend
     - Config
         + __init__.py
         + databaseConfig.py  
     - DataAccess
         + __init__.py
         + sqlConns.py
     - __init__.py
     - api.py
     - main.py
     - setup.py
```

What I am trying to do is import /Config/databaseConfig.py file into /DataAccess/sqlConns.py file. I get the following error when trying to run the sqlConns.py file

```
PS C:\source\repos\aaStats\aaStats> py .\Backend\DataAccess\sqlConns.py      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\source\repos\aaStats\aaStats\Backend\DataAccess\sqlConns.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Config.databaseConfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Config'
```

I have also tried using relative imports, but I am met with another error.

```
PS C:\source\repos\aaStats\aaStats> py .\Backend\DataAccess\sqlConns.py      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\source\repos\aaStats\aaStats\Backend\DataAccess\sqlConns.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..Config import databaseConfig as dbcfg
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Config/databaseConfig.py contains database configuration parameters that I want to reference is various places in my project. It isn't a huge deal if I had to move this single file in order to get it to be referenced properly, but I will want to use structures like this for files later on in my project.

Here are some details about my files:

/Config/__init__.py

```
from . import databaseConfig
```

/DataAccess/__init__.py

```
from . import sqlConns
```

Backend/__init__.py

```
from . import DataAccess
from . import Config
```

Backend/setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='aaStatsApi',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages= ['DataAccess','Config'],
    install_requires=[
        'fastapi==0.63.0',
        'uvicorn==0.13.4',
        'requests==2.25.1',
        'pyodbc==4.0.30',
    ]
)
```

Comment: I would check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python).
2. The fact that you can't perform relative imports so easily is by design, for better or for worse. The ideal way is have your main script in the root (`Backend`) directory and do all your calls from there. The function that has `__name__ == __main__` is your calling function. If you do not *directly* call `Calls.py` or `Configs.py` from a console, but are calling them from another *main* function within your root directory, you should be able to place the following into `Conns.py`:

```py
# FILE: DataAcess\sqlConns.py
from Config.dataBaseConfig import * # or whatever you need to import
```

Again, the key is to ensure that your starting point in from your root project directory.

3. ***NOT RECOMMENDED:***
   For risk of getting downvoted, and I do not recommend this, but *you could append the relative path to your calling class*:

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("../Config"))
from sqlConns import * # or whatever
sys.path.pop() # clear sys.path
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense and everything does work when say importing and accessing ```Configs.py``` from ```api.py```